# SMS Sent/Delivered Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcast Receiver for Sent SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571026/broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms)

I am currently detecting when an SMS is received through a broadcast receiver like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".gathering.SMSNode">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Is there a similar broadcast receiver for detecting when a message is sent?

Comment: The question linked only listed alternatives, but never stated whether a receiver existed or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Handler handler = new Handler();
m_SMSObserver = new SMSObserver(handler);
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"),
true, m_SMSObserver);
```

And this code for separating send/receive events

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null,
null, null);
cur.moveToNext();
String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
if(protocol == null)
        onSMSSend();            
else
        onSMSReceive();
```

Check the following url for reference:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg27154.html