# How to detect sent message?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on the message sending and receiving , i got many answers for message receiving via broadcast receiver , But there is no solution for message sent .

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.test.services.MessageReciver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



public static final String ACTION_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    public static final String ACTION_SENT = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER";

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// this section works only when message received on in case of sent
}
```

**But the broadcast receiver work only for message received not for message sent.**

Answer (score 1):

You should put PendingIntent for SMS Sent and Delivery. 
Please refer the below Syntax:

sendTextMessage (String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text, PendingIntent **sentIntent**, PendingIntent **deliveryIntent**)

**sentIntent** and **deliveryIntent** can be used as a broadcast action and you can fulfil your desired task.

Comment: Thanks But i am sending the message from default message application . I want to detect that message which is sending currnlty from device default application not from the custom application.

Comment: OP doesn't want to send an SMS, he wants to detect when a SMS is sent

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that they are in fact both receive actions, the difference in them being that one is only delivered to the default sms app, while the other is delivered to all sms apps.

> [public static final String SMS_DELIVER_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_DELIVER_ACTION)
>
> Broadcast Action: A new text-based SMS message has been received by the device. This intent will only be delivered to the default sms app.
>
> Constant Value: "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"

---

> [public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)
>
> Broadcast Action: A new text-based SMS message has been received by the device. This intent will be delivered to all registered receivers as a notification.
>
> Constant Value: "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"

There is no action that is broadcasted when a SMS is sent.

For receiving sent SMS broadcasts, check

- [Android Broadcast Receiver for Sent SMS messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990558/android-broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms-messages)
- [SMS Sent/Delivered Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008991/sms-sent-delivered-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: Hi time can you expain what do you want to say .

Comment: @AmitSharma `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"` is not for delivered SMS, but also for received SMS. The name is confusing

Comment: I have edited the question please recheck and let me know whats in you mind

Comment: so i have add only this one in mainefest "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" ?

Comment: @AmitSharma SMS_DELIVER is only delivered to the default SMS app, while SMS_RECEIVED is delivered to all sms apps

Comment: I want to work only with default SMS application . Can you put code in answer that will be helpful

Comment: @AmitSharma refer to the links I added

Comment: Ok , i am going to check